# Parsing specific strings from XML to a SQL db in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I am looking for the best way to parse a specific string from a xml page.

The page in question will have lots of links all with a prefix video and I want to save the number after video. Also has to be a specific line where the video is located.

ex: http://example.com/video/12345/myvid.mp4

So I want to be able to search for video in  and take only the number `12345`.

Also the URL page number and save these both into a db under `vidId`, `pageNum`.

Comment: You might want to put in details like where are these pages stored, what db you want and a sample page. Its fine coz its your first time I think so try elaborating further.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "http://example.com/video/12345/myvid.mp4";
var parts = value.split('/');
var partYouWant = parts[4]; // If you want take 12345 
                            // part[5] if you want take myvid.mp4
```